# Does the iPhone API allow my application to respond to the headset button?

Tags: iphone

I cannot find this in the documentation anywhere.  Does anyone know if this is possible or if it's on a lower level unavailable to 3rd party apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. I looked for this too. Sorry to bear bad news.